# ES6 class extending another class and calling super multiple times?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a class Player and want to extend it to have a class Team.

My logic would be:

```
class Player {
  constructor(name, age) { //class constructor
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  sayName() { //class method
    console.log('Hi, I am ', this.name + '.');
  }
  sayAge() {
    console.log('Hi, I am ', this.age + '.');
  }
}

class Team extends Player {
  constructor(members) {
    var players = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < members; i++) {
      players.push(super(members[i].name, members[i].age));

    }
    this.players = players; // to not call "this" before super
  }

  teamNames() { 
    console.log(this.players);
  }
}

let p = new Player('John', 25);
p.sayName(); // John

var team = [{
  name: 'Jonh',
  age: 25
},{
  name: 'Anna',
  age: 27
}];
var A_Team = new Team(team);
A_Team.temNames();
```

#### fiddle: http://www.es6fiddle.net/ik5s7ale/

But this gives errors and the class does not work. I understand calling `super` inside a loop is wrong, but what would be the solution here? Is the relation between these two classes not a "extend" situation, should I use/declare separated classes for this without extending?

Comment: Yeah I don't understand how Team extends Player. Wouldn't Team have a collection of Players rather than extend it? Like I think there's probably something similar to what you have that would work, but I don't think it makes sense. If you already have a Player class just make `var team` an array of Player objects.

Comment: @azium yes, it would be a collection. But I wanted to have some methods in each player that could be used in Team. But maybe its just a case of calling all the collection methods and keep them separated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a

Comment: You could still of course call the Player methods on the collection items because they will be instances of Player.

Comment: See, if your Team is a Player, it should be able to both `sayName` and `sayAge`. And it's not quite clear how to implement this; you'll have to define your own implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a superclass-subclass situation.

If you have a class X, and you want to create a special, enhanced version of X, then you should extend/subclass it. That's not what's going on in your case; you should simply *compose* the `Team` class, using the `Player` class.

```
class Player {
  constructor(name, age, team) { //class constructor
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.team = team;
  }
  sayName() { //class method
    console.log('Hi, I am ', this.name + '.');
  }
  sayAge() {
    console.log('Hi, I am ', this.age + '.');
  }
}

class Team {
  constructor(members) {
    this.players = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < members; i++) {
      this.players.push(new Player(members[i].name, members[i].age, this));
    }
  }
  teamNames() { 
    console.log(this.players);
  }
}
```

If you want the players to have access to `Team` methods or constants, you're going to have to give the `Player` instances a reference to their parent `Team` instance, and call it as `team.teamMethod()`.

Answer (score 1):

Relation between Team and Player is surely not inheritance.

Team is not the special case of player, but rather Team consists of players.

Correct would be declaring separate classes. You have 2 ways of achieving it, depends of how you are using

- Team takes array of players in parameter of constructor - this is good in most of cases.
- Team is created "empty" and later you set players. Maybe the Team can create instance of that player based on some parameters ( createPlayer(name, age)

---

Well this was for your last part of question, now why your code does not work.

When you call super, you are calling the constructor of parent object.

The parant object is only one and super does not return pointer to it (instead it returns undefined), so you can not push it to the array.

Also you had a few typos in your code.

[See an updated fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ik5t4x31/)

**EDIT**
I Was writting answer and didn't notice another answer posted in the meantime :-)